# How do I use the -ne flag for echo in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, iterm, bash-scripting

I'm trying to create a shell script to take an argument and use it to name a terminal tab. So if the script's name is tabnm, tabnm "test" should rename the current tab "test"

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -ne "\e]1;$1\a"
```

but when i run it I get this output:

```
robin@icarus $ sh tabnm.sh test   
-ne \e]1;test
```

If I just run `echo -ne "\e]1;Test\a"` straight in the shell, the tab is renamed.

Comment: Is /bin/sh a symlink to /bin/bash on your system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the difference between `echo` in `/bin/sh` vs. your interactive shell.  I suggest using `printf` instead, and see [The UNIX and the `echo`](http://everything2.com/title/The+UNIX+and+the+Echo).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your shell recognizes different escape codes than your `/bin/sh`.

`/bin/sh` probably doesn't recognize `\e` as the escape character. Try `\033` instead.

You can also replace `\a` by the equivalent code`\007` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code for bash, you should say so in your shebang line:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -ne "\e]1;$1\a"
```